# Order concatenated left join results

Tags: mysql, group-by, many-to-many, left-join, group-concat

I have following tables:

```
Table: person
 id  |  name
  1  |  John
  2  |  Ana
  3  |  Thomas

Table: fruit 
 id  |  name
  1  |  orange
  2  |  banana
  3  |  grapefruit
  4  |  lemon
  5  |  apricot

Table: person_fruit
person_id | fruit_id
    1     |     1
    1     |     3
    2     |     1
    2     |     2
    1     |     5
```

As you guessed, the person_fruit table serves as the many to many relation.

I'm doing a query for listing all the persons and their favourite fruits concatenated in a string. My problem is that I cannot display their favourite fruits ordered by fruit name like:

```
John   | apricot, grapefruit, orange
Ana    | banana, orange
Thomas | NULL
```

My current MySQL query looks like:

```
SELECT 
  p.name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(f.name SEPARATOR ', ') fruit
FROM
  person p
LEFT JOIN person_fruit pf
  ON p.id = pf.person_id
LEFT JOIN `fruit` `f`
  ON f.id = pf.fruit_id
GROUP BY
  p.id
```

how can you sort the concatenated left join results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ORDER BY inside the GROUP_CONCAT.

Also p.name should be in GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT 
  p.name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(f.name  ORDER by f.name ASC SEPARATOR ',') fruit
FROM
  person p
LEFT JOIN person_fruit pf
  ON p.id = pf.person_id
LEFT JOIN `fruit` `f`
  ON f.id = pf.fruit_id
GROUP BY
  p.name
```